# RichText Box in sharepoint 2010 visual webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rich-text

I have a rich text box in share point 2010 visual web part...i want to get only first 2 lines of the rich text box..any suggestions?
i tried getting the line by using cRichtextbox.Lines but it throws an error saying

microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.inputformtextbox does not contain defination for lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.inputformtextbox.text.aspx) property of the InputFormTextBox control, and parse the first two lines manually. It's quite easy actually, something like this:

```
var firstTwoLines = String.Join("\n", MyRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n').Take(2).ToArray());
```

Comment: Excellent! this is what i was looking for